# scp refuses to do anything but print usage

Tags: scp

I'm trying to copy a file on my home network using `scp`. However, every time I run it, it just prints usage instructions.

```
$ scp alex@192.168.0.4:ipdetect-0.6.tar.bz2
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the destination.

```
scp alex@192.168.0.4:ipdetect-0.6.tar.bz2 .
```